# How to make a GET request (MongoDB -- Express)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is POST request.
But how to make a GET request?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const signUpTemplateCopy = require('../models/SignUpModels')

router.post('/signup', (request, response) => {
    const signedUpUser = new signUpTemplateCopy({
        fullName: request.body.fullName,
        username: request.body.username,
        email: request.body.email,
        password: request.body.password
    })
    signedUpUser.save()
    .then(data => response.json(data))
    .catch(error => response.json(error))
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the database in MongoDB.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included both probable codes for GET request. First one is for getting back all the users in your db and the second one is to get specific user by using the ObjectId which you have to pass as a parameter. Let me know if it works.

```
//Get all user
router.get('/getUsers', (request, response) => {
    signUpTemplateCopy.find()
    .then(data => response.json(data))
    .catch(error => response.json(error))
)};

//Get user by ObjectID
router.get('/getUserByID/:id', (request, response) => {
    signUpTemplateCopy.findById(request.params.id)
    .then(data => response.json(data))
    .catch(error => response.json(error))
)};
```

Comment: yes it does. Thank you very much! Could you tell me if there were queryParams such as email or username how could we create them? and make sth like a filter-get query?

Comment: yeah you can do that as well. for e.g. const { email } = req.body; const user = signUpTemplateCopy.findById(req.params.id, { email: email })

Comment: I wonder how the second one works. Shouldnt it have dynamic parameters? Such as:  "/getUserByID/:id"

Comment: i forgot to add id but yeah rest of it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are get requests as an addition to @SHIBAB answer. And I think you dont need to use "Router()" here

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/members", function(req, res){
  SignUpModels.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).then(function(records){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(records))
  });
});

app.get("/members/:id", function(req, res){
  SignUpModels.find({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(records){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(records))
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```